# linux umask for sudo and apache

Tags: linux, ubuntu, umask

I want to make 002 the system-wide umask for all users (in Ubuntu). I managed to do so for all regular users using the instructions provided by @ephemient ([From this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220531/how-to-set-system-wide-umask), thanks for that!). However I got 2 more problems.

Firstly, when sudoing, the root user seems to follow it's own settings, making files with the permissions 644 (instead of 664).

Secondly, the apache user (www-data) also seems to follow it's own settings (the same used by root?), making files with the permissions 644 (instead of 664). I don't like to put `umask 002` in `/etc/apache2/envvars`, I'd rather change the setting assigning the 002 umask to apache in the first place.

How can I tackle those last 2 issues?

Comment: If you `sudo umask`, do you see `022` or `002`?

Comment: `sudo umask` gives `sudo: umask: command not found` but `sudo -s` followed by `umask` gives `0022`

Comment: Ah, I forgot that `umask` was a shell builtin. Anyway, it looks like it is setup correctly for root. Does `sudo touch testfile` produce a file with the permissions you want?

Comment: No, since I want the umask 0002 to be used (which is correct for all other users exept www-data and any user logged into via sudo). Files created via sudo (and www-data) are 755 and I want them to be 775.

Comment: FYI: when I log in directly as `root` (not via sudo), umask is also `0002` as expected

Comment: This may be a `pam_umask` issue. I would suggest doing it the "classic" way and putting `umask 002` in `/etc/profile`. It might fix your problem.

Comment: No, I tried that at first but it didn't work (it worked just as much as the `pam_umask` solution)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solved my own problems.

For the sudo permissions, I executed `sudo visudo` and added the line `Defaults umask = 0002` to the end.

For the Apache user, I added the line `umask 0002` to the end of the `/etc/apache2/envvars` (I couldn't find any better solution).