# How can I set default umask in gnome on Debian-Stretch?

Tags: permissions, debian, gnome-3, umask

I would like the permissions on files that I create with gnome apps (e.g., gedit and libreoffice) to respect the umask I set.

I have set umask to 027 in ~/.profile and /etc/login.defs. I've also followed the directions from here by adding a line to /etc/pam.d/common-session: [How to set system wide umask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220531/how-to-set-system-wide-umask)

Nothing is working.

I am able to get the umask setting to work if I create files in vi or nano from gnome-terminal (after setting umask 027 in .bashrc). But I would like to get this umask respected in gnome apps like gedit also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnome applications in question are likely launched by systemd user instance, which sets the umask to 022 regardless the umask configured using PAM.

This question has also been [asked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254378/how-to-set-umask-for-the-entire-gnome-session/379329) on U&L SE and has more answers there.

Comment: Is there any way to change the default umask now without having to wait for the bug fix you initiated?

Comment: I am not currently aware of any workarounds; umask set by pam_umask is replaced by systemd's default umask.