# Making new files automatically executable?

Tags: file, unix, umask

Is it possible to make all newly created files have the execute permission when they are created? Why can't I grant it by default?

Comment: How are you creating files?

Comment: You can, you just need to change the `umask` for the user creating the files. Making things executable by default is **really not recommended**.

Comment: You might want to check out [this][1] topic.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580584/setting-default-permissions-for-newly-created-files-and-sub-directories-under-a

Comment: @BoristheSpider Actually I don't think it would work. `umask` only lowers the default, not elevating it.

Answer (score 5):

umask for files is subtracted from 666 and for directories it is subtracted from 777.  So if your umask is 002 and you create a directory, you get 775 (777 - 002), and if you create a file you get 664 (666 - 002).

Comment: How does your answer solve the question? As cremefraiche noted in the third answer below: "This is not an acceptable answer. The default umask for files is 666, and you cannot elevate permissions with umask, only set them lower than the default."

Answer (score 2):

The umask merely subtracts default file and directory permissions.

```
777 initial file permissions
111 execute bit is not set by default
---
666 default file permissions
022 subtract default Unix umask
---
644 voila, final file permissions
```

The execute bit must be set for the owner to cd into a directory of their creation, so user-execute permission is set, resulting in directory permissions of 744, when using the above umask.

I have found no way to setting which would set the execute, by default. This would be bad mojo, anyway, but I am currently researching for a cyber security course I am writing.

Answer (score 0):

To provide a consolidated answer: File permissions are rw-rw-rw (0666) by default for pretty much any Unix tool (as recommended by POSIX) and umask just subtracts permissions bits but cannot add bits which means it's not possible to create files by default with the executable bit set.
Some background can be found in these SE Q+A's:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211481/why-doesnt-umask-set-the-execute-bit
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287278/why-doesnt-umask-change-execute-permissions-on-files

Answer (score -5):

In a safe way? No.
In an unsafe manner: just change the `umask` by adding `umask xxx` in your `~/.bashrc` file, where `xxx` represents the permission mask you wish.

**Notes:**

1. This is unsafe (did I already mention it? Other did.)
2. It may leads to many issues. One being the creation of files
   disallowed on some systems)

**Recommended way**:

Only do it for files that actually need the execute permission.

```
chmod +x /the/file
```

Comment: This isn't just unsafe in theory, it flat doesn't work. Every `umask` I've tried straight up ignores the numbers when it comes to the execute bit.

Comment: Well, then I guess it just depends on the flavor of linux your are using.

Comment: @Jean Can you give an example of a umask on any system that allows you to create an executable file by default?

Comment: This is not an acceptable answer. The default umask for files is 666, and you cannot elevate permissions with umask, only set them lower than the default.

Comment: What you do with an apache server for example? Do you continuously update file permissions on new files as you add them? That sounds like a real rigmarole.