# How do you automatically set permissions on a file when uploaded using a sftp

Tags: permissions, sftp

Hello i currently have a folder set up that can have files uploaded to using a sftp.

```
 drwxrwxr-x. 2 cypress cypress  4096 Apr 30 15:24 sourceit
```

But when i file gets uploaded it gets uploaded as

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 cypress sftpusrs    7 Apr 30 15:24 test.file
```

what do i have to do to set it up so when i file gets uploaded it will automatically set the permissions to

```
drwxrwxr-x. 1 cypress sftpusrs    7 Apr 30 15:24 test.file
```

Thank you for your help.

I currently have everything set up in openssh sshd_config for ftping

```
Match user cypress
ChrootDirectory /mnt/cypress
AllowTCPForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Comment: You will need to edit your FTP server config.Do you know which FTP server you use ? ProFTPD or vsftpd or else ?

Comment: i am currently using sshd for ftping.

Comment: lftp is the client. What are you using on the server. When connecting to your server, you should get the version and type of FTP server in the logs.

Comment: i have everything set up in ssh sshd_config for ftping

Comment: Are you conencitng using port 22 or 21 ? i suspect you are not even using FTP but SFTP which are 2 very different things.

Comment: i am using sftp so connecting using port 22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify or Add this line to your sshd_config

```
ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 2
```

which should apply a umask of 002.

With umask or SFTP, there is no way to automaticaly put a file executable, it would be a huge security risk. You must run chmod in a separate command in order to do that.

Comment: if i wanted the umask to be 775 would i just type in -u 775

Comment: added info on my post. look here if you need more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599951/making-new-files-automatically-executable