# SQLite WAL/SHM not deleted when another user runs a program

Tags: database, sqlite, wal

On a Linux system, I have a SQLite database created with Write-ahead logging, say, by user "bob".

/home/bob/sqliteTest/test.db

I also have a compiled program, called "sqliteTest" with sqlite commands contained within.

If user "bob" runs the sqliteTest program, it runs to completion and there are no wal shm files in the directory where test.db is.

To allow other users to access test.db, I have allowed everyone to have write/execute permissions to the sqliteTest directory.

So, user "joe" comes along and decides to run the sqliteTest program.
"joe" runs the program to completion, but when he is done, the wal and shm files still remain in the directory, with owner "joe", read-only, except writable by "joe".

Like I said, I've changed the permissions to allow writes/executes by anyone. So, this is really stumping me. If the "bob" user has none of these files after the process completes, it would seem like the code is cleaning up after itself correctly.
Thanks for any help!
Kevin B

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting default permissions for newly created files and sub-directories under a directory in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580584/setting-default-permissions-for-newly-created-files-and-sub-directories-under-a)