# PHP move_upload_file needs permission rwx to store file

Tags: php, unix, permissions

I am using the following code to upload and move a file to the folder "film_images":

```
$filepath = '../images/film_images/';
echo '<br />Trying to store file at ' . $filepath;
if (!move_uploaded_file(
    $_FILES['teaserimage']['tmp_name'],
    sprintf($filepath . '%s.%s',
    'test',
    $ext))) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
}
```

However, as many people here, I always got a

> Failed to open stream: Permission Denied

exception in PHP. Then I went to the server and, using the `setfacl` command I gave permission `rw-` to the user `www-data`, which is the user running this PHP script. Using `rw-` I still got the exception. Only when I switched rights to `rwx`, i.e. when I gave `www-data` full control on this folder, it worked. Now I wonder two things:

1. Why is it necessary to give the user execution rights in order to write a file?
2. Is there a way to write the file without giving execution rights to the user? I fear that somebody might upload code, hidden in an image file, and execute it on my server.

Answer (score 1):

You need set default permission on folder if create new files, first chmod it: `chmod g+s images/film_images //set permission what you need`

second you need set default permissions on create files/folders:

```
setfacl -R -d -m group:www-data:rwx /path/to/your/dir //set permission what you need
```

Comment: I did as you said, now instead of the entry `user:www-data:rwx` I have the entry `default:user:www-data:rw-`. With this setting, again, I get the "Permission Denied" error. Any idea what went wrong?
It seems to work only with the entry user:www-data:rwx.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I figured it out. Thanks Paulius S. and his answer, which got me on the right track.

The folder ist owned by me. First, following the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580584/setting-default-permissions-for-newly-created-files-and-sub-directories-under-a), I use

```
chmod g+rwxs dirname
```

to ensure that files created in the directory are owned by the group I belong to. In particular, www-data is not part of this group. Then using

```
setfacl -m u:www-data:rwx dirname
```

I give full access to the directory to the user www-data. Now www-data can upload a, but this file automatically belongs to the group set above (which www-data does not belong to) and hence www-data has no execution right, although he can execute in the folder in general.