# CentOS change permissions of newly created folders

Tags: linux

This should be pretty easy however it's tricky to Google.

How can I set it so every time "username" creates a new folder, it has 775 permissions, instead of 755? Basically to change the default assigned permissions for new folders.

Thanks,
Hristian

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting default permissions for newly created files and sub-directories under a directory in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580584/setting-default-permissions-for-newly-created-files-and-sub-directories-under-a)

Comment: Take a look at `umask`. It is a shell command and can be used in the setup of the login shell for example. So in files like ~/.profile or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set may set a correct umask.

You can find extra documentation at http://centoscert.com/content/what-umask-and-how-setup-default-umask

You can modify the one in `/etc/profile` (replace 022 by 002) if you want to change for the whole system.

But careful, this also impact access rights of 'standard' files (not only folders).